# GDB doesn't let me read argv memory segment

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, gdb, argv

I have this simple script written in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void usage(char *program_name) {
   printf("Usage: %s <message> <# of times to repeat>\n", program_name);
   exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int i, count;

//  if(argc < 3)      // If less than 3 arguments are used,
//    usage(argv[0]); // display usage message and exit.

   count = atoi(argv[2]); // convert the 2nd arg into an integer
   printf("Repeating %d times..\n", count);

   for(i=0; i < count; i++)
      printf("%3d - %s\n", i, argv[1]); // print the 1st arg
}
```

And I'm making some test with GDB.

I did this:

```
(gdb) run test
Starting program: /home/user/Desktop/booksrc/convert2 test

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a56e56 in ____strtoll_l_internal () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

Obviusly it goes in segmentation fault because to work the program needs three argv. And I commented the lines that do the control. So it goes in error.

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffff7a56e56 in ____strtoll_l_internal () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7a53a80 in atoi () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00005555555546ea in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe958) at convert2.c:14
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x5555555546d2: file convert2.c, line 14.
(gdb) run test
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /home/user/Desktop/booksrc/convert2 test

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe958) at convert2.c:14
14     count = atoi(argv[2]); // convert the 2nd arg into an integer
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a56e56 in ____strtoll_l_internal () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) x/3xw 0x7fffffffe958 // this is memory of the "argv" some line before
0x7fffffffe958: 0xffffebfe  0x00007fff  0xffffec22
(gdb) x/s 0xffffebfe
0xffffebfe: <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffebfe>
(gdb) x/s 0x00007fff
0x7fff: <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff>
(gdb) x/s 0xffffec22
0xffffec22: <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffec22>
```

In theory, with "x/s" I should have seen the commandline in the first address and "test" in the second address and the null in the third. But nothing. If I copy paste that address to a ascii to string converter, it gives me data without any sense. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure that you have the command line parameter set? Always check.

Comment: how can I? i'm new with C

Comment: by uncommenting the check in your code. You have commented it probably because it did not allow you to go ahead. You need to have the command line options set and thr `argc` **has** to be `3`

Comment: nono I commented it just to examine with gdb, just to practice. I did it on purpose

Comment: why? Set the arguments in gdb as in my answer. If you had to comment it - your gdb debugging is wrong, as you do not have the command line arguments set

Comment: It's from the book "Hacking: The Art of Exploitation". It's funny because I encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your platform uses 64bit pointers, so try :

```
(gdb) x/3xg 0x7fffffffe958
```

to display the 64bit pointers in the `argv` array, and then :

```
(gdb) x/s 0x00007fffffffebfe
```

or just :

```
(gdb) p argv[0]
```

Comment: It works!! Thanks! But why does 0x00007fff gives me null while it should be the third argv (0xffffec22, that is "test", and should be the second address (that is null). I don't have to consider the order of the addresses in relation of position of argv?

Comment: @AllExJ : 0x00007fff is not a valid address - it's the most significant half of an address. To get the second string in the `argv` array, you need the full address : 0x7fffffffec22 . Or just make your life easy, and do `p argv[1]`.

Comment: also, is it wrong to copy this memory addresses to an hex to text site and convert them?

Comment: @AllExJ : these hex values are memory addresses. They represent the *location* of the string, *not* the string itself. You need to examine (x) the memory at that location, and interpret it as a string (s) like shown above, to display the string. So, no : converting the address to text won't give you the string.

Comment: oh, thanks. I got that in 64 bit systems it's convenient to examine with giant instead of words. It's just few days I'm practicing with C. Anyway, `p argv[1]` gives me this error: `No symbol "argv" in current context.
`

Comment: @AllExJ : to make the `argv` symbol available, jut step once after reaching the breakpoint you set (you set the breakpoint on the `main` symbol, rather than the start of the `main` function).

Answer (score 1):

First of all always check if the command line is correct

Uncomment the check from your code.

Then in the `gdb` set the arguments (before running it)

```
(gdb) set args "hello world" 12
```